# Google Maps dynamic location based on seaech

Tags: javascript, google-maps

**I've created a map using Google.maps.Map().**

I've 2 input field specifying the longitude and latitude. I want to change the map center from the current location to the specified location(based on lat and lng) without making GET request.

How do I do that using javascript?

Comment: Follow the guidance in the following link :https://phppot.com/php/search-location-with-google-maps-javascript-api-place-autocomplete/

Comment: In order to give you a best solution you need come up with a code that you have tried where we can analyze and give you a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your api key to the google map api load, and this will work

```js
function initMap() {
  var centerCoordinates = new google.maps.LatLng(37.6, -95.665);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: centerCoordinates,
    zoom: 4
  });
  var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

  var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
  });

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById("location-error").style.display = 'none';
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      document.getElementById("location-error").style.display = 'inline-block';
      document.getElementById("location-error").innerHTML = "Cannot Locate '" + input.value + "' on map";
      return;
    }

    map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = input.value;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCXMpUMMrjVgbWeWF99SfuFQhe06-ST62s&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
  <div>
    <div id="label">Location search</div>
  </div>
  <div id="pac-container">
    <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter a location">
    <div id="location-error"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
  <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon"> <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br> <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```